# Enterprise Bot template not resuming MainDialog in single step WaterfallDialog

Tags: c#, botframework

When starting a dialog saying *I want to talk to a human* using the Enterprise Bot Template, the WaterfallDialog starts, displays the contact card and ends the flow by calling `EndDialogAsync()`.

However, MainDialogs `CompleteAsync()` method is never called. Thus the bot is not asking for further help.

I noticed that in multistep WaterfallDialogs this works correctly. I believe that this has somehow to do with the [RouterDialog.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/AI/blob/master/templates/Enterprise-Template/src/csharp/EnterpriseBotSample/EnterpriseBotSample/Dialogs/Shared/RouterDialog.cs) implementation, but could not make sense of it.

[EscalateDialog.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/AI/blob/ad124bbd8ee5d3405bda68190ded85d57ae924d3/templates/Enterprise-Template/src/csharp/EnterpriseBotSample/EnterpriseBotSample/Dialogs/Escalate/EscalateDialog.cs#L31)

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> SendPhone(WaterfallStepContext sc, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await _responder.ReplyWith(sc.Context, EscalateResponses.ResponseIds.SendPhoneMessage);
    return await sc.EndDialogAsync();
}
```

[MainDialog.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/AI/blob/ad124bbd8ee5d3405bda68190ded85d57ae924d3/templates/Enterprise-Template/src/csharp/EnterpriseBotSample/EnterpriseBotSample/Dialogs/Main/MainDialog.cs#L160)

```
protected override async Task CompleteAsync(DialogContext dc, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    // The active dialog's stack ended with a complete status
    await _responder.ReplyWith(dc.Context, MainResponses.ResponseIds.Completed);
}
```

Comment: Did you get the Enterprise bot from the AI repo or did you start with a VSIX template?

Comment: @KyleDelaney honestly I don’t remember. It’s already 3 month ago when I started the project. Are you trying to point me to an issue that might be solved in latest commit?

Comment: No, I'm just trying to reproduce your behavior faithfully

Comment: If I have to guess I would say I used VSIX. Not sure, though. Looking forward for your analysis. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just created a new enterprise bot today and I'm afraid I can't reproduce your issue. `MainDialog.CompleteAsync` gets executed after `EscalateDialog.SendPhone` just as [expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLJh8.png). Since you said you started the project 3 months ago, is it possible that you haven't updated to Bot Builder 4.3? While I couldn't find this particular bug in the GitHub repo, it still seems very possible that this was a bug in the SDK that's been fixed. Please check the versions of your NuGet packages and let me know what they are. I'm using 4.3.1.

Comment: Hey Sebastian, are you still working on this?

Comment: Hello @KyleDelaney - sorry for the delay. I was off for Easter :-). Based on your input, I've solved the issue myself and found the root cause (including PR). See my answer. Thanks for pushing me in the right direction! - best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, this issue no longer occures in the latest enterprise bot template. I verified this myself today using version **4.3.0.171** of Enterprise Bot Template from [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BotBuilder.botbuilderv4enterprise).

If you're as me started with a previous version of the template and you want the same behaviour, then you have to change the `RouterDialog.cs` file.

Simply add the following lines of code in the `OnContinueDialogAsync` handler method:

```
...
case DialogTurnStatus.Empty:
{
    await this.RouteAsync(innerDc);
    // FIX: Waterfalls with no turns should Complete.
    if (innerDc.Stack.Count == 0)
        await CompleteAsync(innerDc);
    break;
}
...
```

After knowing where the problem came from, I could find the related [GitHub PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/AI/pull/644) merged on January 30 2019.

**Side by side comparision of the changed file:**

[image: code fix]

**Result after fix is applied:**

[image: result]